# How to set run for indexon unix timestamp in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

The is how my path looks in Firebase:

```
/test/minute/us/1399855161.json  {"me":1.12182333333,"you":1.12167,"event_count":3}

/test/minute/we/1399855161.json  {"me":1.12182333333,"you":1.12167,"event_count":3}
```

How do I setup a rule so I can index based on timestamp in Firebase where `1399855161` is the unix time stamp?

Currently I have the below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "local": {
      ".indexOn": ["us","we"]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to query based on date range. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your have timestamps as your keys. Those are already indexed, so you don't have to explicitly add an index for them. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data#defining_data_indexes):

> A node's key is indexed automatically, so there is no need to index it explicitly.

You can query by:

```
var now = Date.now(),
    yesterday = now - 24*60*60*1000,
    tomorrow = now + 24*60*60*1000,
    query = ref.child("/test/minute/us")
               .orderByKey()
               .startAt(""+yesterday)
               .endAt(""+tomorrow");
```